# secure connection with x509 certificates

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, x509

I create my CA certificate out of my secret generated private key and add it to every host's trusted root certificate authorities.

Then I receive a request for a certificate from that host and sign it with my private key, defining the valid period.

And I guess it's fine when I make a request to host (his certificate is validated by my CA, which is trusted), but what happens when he requests me?

Comment: Eh? What? Signing your Certificate message with your private key, which certainly happens, doesn't define the validity period. That's determined by the CA, not by you. When he 'requests me' you send your certificate, and a signature, as you have already described. What's your question again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I create my CA certificate out of my secret generated private key and add it to every host's trusted root certificate authorities.

So you are the CA.

> Then I receive a request for a certificate from that host and sign it with my private key, defining the valid period.

So again you are the CA.

> And I guess it's fine when I make a request to host (his certificate is validated by my CA, which is trusted), but what happens when he requests me?

The CA doesn't make requests to hosts. So at this point you are no longer the CA, you must be the client. So, as the client, you receive a CertificateRequest, specifying acceptable CAs, and if you have a certificate signed by one of those CAs, you reply with that certificate. If you don't, you don't reply at all. If the server required a certificate and didn't get one, at this point it will just close the connection.

Comment: Thanks. For now as I understood, all I need is to make sure that REQUESTER has the CA certificate in its trusted zone and every RESPONSER has a certificate signed by that CA's private key. Right?